# Fetch the value of li tag after clicking a div in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-lists, fetch

I have the following code:

```
<div class="ranges">
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In jQuery is it possible to fetch the value of `li` after clicking the div which has the `ranges` class?

```
$('.ranges').click(function(){
    //code
});
```

Comment: yes, go on and try some things

Comment: There are checkmarks close to each answer. SO recommends that you click one of them if you believe that item solved your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its much easier to attach the event to the `li` elements themselves:

```
$('.ranges li').click(function(){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

If you did want to attach the event only to the `.ranges` element you could delegate it, like this:

```
$('.ranges').on('click', 'li', function(){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get the value of `li` use below code:

```
$('.ranges').click(function(){
   $.each($(this).find('li'),function(index,val){
         alert($(this).find('li')[index].text()); //here will be value of li
   });
});
```

**EDITED:**

If you want the value of clicked `li` then use this code:

```
$('.ranges li').click(function(){
     alert($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan **clicking the div having ranges class** this is the requirement of OP.

Comment: Yes, but the OP is after getting the value of the one which was clicked, not all of the `li` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is.

```
$('.ranges').click(function(e){
  console.log(e.target);
});
```